# JavaScript bytecode compiler?

Tags: javascript, compiler-construction, bytecode

For a project I'm tangentially working on, I need a way to compile JavaScript into some intermediate language or bytecode so that I can single-step through it.  I know that many of the JavaScript engines in modern browsers do something like this, but they don't make the resulting bytecode accessible.  Is there a good off-the-shelf tool for this sort of JavaScript compilation?

Comment: Why don't you then just use a debugger of a browser? I mean, you want to step through the code and therefore you're going to translate it into some intermediate code so you can step through it...?
Also interesting maybe: .NET supports JScript - maybe that helps you?

Comment: The idea is to have students write JavaScript code in a web browser and then to be able to run it in the browser with a debugger available.  Many browsers do have good debuggers in them, but sometimes they're really hard to use or have weird side-effects, like locking up the browser except for the debugging console.  For that reason, .NET won't be very useful, since this should run in a browser on any OS.  Still, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not exactly sure of your needs, however maybe [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/) could work for you.

> The JavaScript compiler translates
>   JavaScript source into Java class
>   files. The resulting Java class files
>   can then be loaded and executed at
>   another time, providing a convenient
>   method for transfering JavaScript, and
>   for avoiding translation cost.

More about the compile function is located [here](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/jsc.html).